# Spring 4.0.6 with quartz 1.8.6 : setCronExpression method is not exposed to CronTriggerBean class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am using spring version 4.0.6 and quartz with it, version 1.8.6. The problem is, when I try to use a configuration class instead of xml (with @Configuration annotation), I am not able to set the cron expression with the method

> CronTriggerBean ctBean = new CronTriggerBean();
>   ctBean.setCronExpression("0 35 15 ? * MON *");

Please tell me if there is a version compatibility issue.

The exact error is this:

> The method setCronExpression(String) is undefined for the type CronTriggerBean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `CronTriggerFactoryBean`:

```
    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean() {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 35 15 ? * MON *");
        return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
    }
    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobClass(YOUR_CLASS.class);
        return jobDetailFactoryBean;
    }
```

and then:

```
CronTrigger trigger = cronTriggerFactoryBean.getObject();
```

The documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/CronTriggerFactoryBean.html) says:
"NOTE: This FactoryBean works against both Quartz 1.x and Quartz 2.0/2.1, in contrast to the older CronTriggerBean class.".

Comment: `@Bean
 public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {  
  SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
  Trigger[] triggers = new Trigger[1];
  triggers[0] = cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject();
  schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(triggers);
  return schedulerFactoryBean;
 }`  
  It did work for me as well, but had to change the CronTrigger step as above, just in case it helps someone.